# XE4 iOS app: Unable to install package. (e8008015)

Tags: ios, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe4

I took part in the XE4 beta and despite having problems that the .ipa could never be produced (error message in Delphi "Invalid ipa option"), the app was always actually physically deployed to the device, but was never created in the Mac scratch-dir.

If I copied and pasted the paclient command into the command prompt though, it worked. My QC issue on this was closed as resolved, but it wasn't.

Now with XE4, using the same settings I had with the beta, I'm getting this error when deploying to the device:

```
Unable to launch process on '10.0.0.60' using the parameters from the 'Delphi_XE4' profile.
The following error was returned: 'Unable to install package. (e8008015)'
```

The app deploys to the XCode Simulator OK, so the connection details are correct. During deployment, I can see PAServer accepting the commands on the Mac, but whether I use the Debug or Ad-hoc build type, I get this error.

I checked the device logs in XCode and found the following:

```
Apr 29 08:48:37 Js-iPhone-4S installd[54] <Error>: 0x2ffed000 handle_install: Install of "/var/mobile/Media/PublicStaging/iOS_Location.app" requested by mobile_installation_proxy
Apr 29 08:48:37 Js-iPhone-4S installd[54] <Error>: 0x2ffed000 MobileInstallationInstall_Server: Installing app iOS_Location
Apr 29 08:48:37 Js-iPhone-4S installd[54] <Error>: Apr 29 08:48:37 SecTrustEvaluate [leaf CriticalExtensions IssuerCommonName]
Apr 29 08:48:38 Js-iPhone-4S installd[54] <Error>: 0x2ffed000 verify_signer_identity: MISValidateSignatureAndCopyInfo failed for /var/tmp/install_staging.XRYC1t/iOS_Location.app/iOS_Location: 0xe8008015
Apr 29 08:48:38 Js-iPhone-4S installd[54] <Error>: 0x2ffed000 do_preflight_verification: Could not verify executable at /var/tmp/install_staging.XRYC1t/iOS_Location.app
Apr 29 08:48:38 Js-iPhone-4S installd[54] <Error>: 0x2ffed000 install_application: Could not preflight application install
Apr 29 08:48:38 Js-iPhone-4S mobile_installation_proxy[1595] <Error>: 0x3baabb88 MobileInstallationInstall: failed with -1
Apr 29 08:48:38 Js-iPhone-4S mobile_installation_proxy[1595] <Error>: handle_install: Installation failed
Apr 29 08:48:38 Js-iPhone-4S installd[54] <Error>: 0x2ffed000 handle_install: API failed
```

It seems the code signing stage is not working, even though I'm using the same mobile provision as I used all throughout the beta process. I've walked through all of the stages in the Docwiki, but nothing changes this error. My iPhone Developer & Distribution certificates are valid and only a few months old.

This happens on my project and any of the sample projects installed with XE4 as well. In the above log, I was using the iOS_Location sample.

I'm frustrated because I've seen the beta working but now can't get the full release to work. I'm sure it's environmental but I'm running out of ideas.

XE3 is installed in the same PC, but the forums suggest this is ok.
XCode on the Mac is fully up to date.
Remember, it deploys to the simulator on the mac fine.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "My QC issue on this was closed as resolved, but it wasn't." - It's worth reopening or filing another bug, in that case.

Comment: Thanks David. I have XE4 working without any errors now so I can't reopen it in all fairness.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found out what caused this. Although I had selected Debug or Release as the Target Build Type, I had not selected "Ad-hoc" under the iOS Device platform.

Comment: Sorry for brining this up again so late, but I think I have the same problem. If I build/deploy I do not get any .pia file or error message. However, if I pick run I get same error as you. I am not sure, but was your situation the same as mine: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17993448/delphi-ios-no-ipa-file-generated (I believe I have selected the correct items, but this problem is bugging me out, so figured it was worth trying to ask)

Comment: Once I changed the target type, I've never seen the error again, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

This error comes because the target iOS device has not been provisioned with the provisioning profile that you configured in RAD Studio. 
Either [**provision the target device with the configured provisioning profile**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE6/en/Provisioning_an_iOS_Application), or change the RAD Studio project configuration to a different provisioning profile. See [**Completing the Provisioning Page**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE6/en/Completing_the_Provisioning_Page). 
Ensure that your provisioning data in RAD Studio matches your iOS developer account, and not your Mac developer account. Be specially careful when you specify your [**iOS developer certificate name**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE6/en/Provisioning#Certificate_Names).