# Delphi iOS - no .ipa file generated - unable to install library (e800080)

Tags: ios, delphi, submission

So I am following this Delphi guide on app store submission:
http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/Deploying_Your_iOS_Application_for_Submission_to_the_App_Store

So in section **Generate an Application Archive File for Your Application** it states it should generate an .ipa file in my project directory + scratch directory on Mac. But it does not as far as I can tell. Instead I get an able about Delphi unable to install library using the paramaters defined in my profile.

I have attached a screenshot that shows I am building and deploying for release/iosdevice/appstore.

[image]

And here is the error I get:

[image]

And here is my project options / provisioning:

[image]

Worth mentioning that one has to use **/Users/username/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/letters-and-digits.mobileprovision** for it to work, otherwise scratchdir is used for search.

And here is version info:

[image]

I have used **com.example.myname** (what you see in **xCode - Organizer - Applications**) instead of **idcode.com.example** (what you see in **Xcode - Organizer - Provisioning profiles**) for **CFBundleIdentifier**. I *think* that is correct although not 100% sure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I still have problems. (Apparently Application Loader believes my bundle id is wrong even though I have tried changing it to match what it requests.) I managed to get over this. I just needed to added "Developer program ID" (which works if you have a valid provisioning profile listed)

Comment: For refernece, I still have problems generating a correct .pia file with correct bundle ID. I started a new SO for that since that is a new questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18000507/delphi-and-ios-application-loader-complaining-about-bundle-id

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to run your iOS application on an iOS device that does not match the iOS form factor (UIDeviceFamily) defined for your project. For example, you might be trying to run your iOS application on an iPad, but your application is configured to run on an iPhone only. 
Select **Project > Options > [Version Info](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE6/en/Version_Info#Mac_OS_X_and_iOS_Version_Info)** and choose a UIDeviceFamily value that matches your iOS device. For example, choose **iPhone & iPad** to run your application on any iOS device.