# Delphi XE4 and iOS Application Loader complaining "This bundle is invalid"

Tags: ios, delphi

I can not pick a correct **CFBundleIdentifier** value it seems.

...

in KeyChain I have this certificate:

```
iPhone Distribution: ExampleCompany (DistCertificateID)
```

In my developer.apple.com account I have defined app:

```
Name: LongReadableName 
Prefix: DistCertificateID 
ID: com.example.*

Name: Xcode iOS Wildcard App ID
Prefix: DistCertificateID 
ID: *
```

In **iTunesConnect** I have name SkuID + BundleID **appname**

...

I have then tried to enter and deploy with following values with different error messages:

- appname

> This bundle is invalid. The application-identifier entitlement is not
>   formatted correctly; it should contain your 10-character App ID Seed,
>   followed by a dot, followed by your bundle identifier:
>   **0000000000.appname**

- DistCertificateID.appname

> The Bundle ID **DistCertificateID.appname** defined in your Xcode
>   Project does not match the Bundle ID that you entered for this app in
>   iTunes Connect **appname**.

- DistCertificateID.com.example

> The Bundle ID **DistCertificateID.com.example** defined in your Xcode
>   Project does not match the Bundle ID that you entered for this app in
>   iTunes Connect **appname**.

- DistCertificateID.com.example.*

> The Bundle ID **DistCertificateID.com.example.*** defined in your Xcode
>   Project does not match the Bundle ID that you entered for this app in
>   iTunes Connect **appname**.

- DistCertificateID.com.example.appname

> The Bundle ID **DistCertificateID.com.example.appname** defined in your Xcode
>   Project does not match the Bundle ID that you entered for this app in
>   iTunes Connect **appname**.

- com.example.appname

> The Bundle ID **com.example.appname** defined in your Xcode
>   Project does not match the Bundle ID that you entered for this app in
>   iTunes Connect **appname**.

I think I have tried everything I could think of...

I speculate if the issue could be resolved by a different iTunesConnect configuration/upload although I have now idea at present how to create one that would solve the problems listed here. But just in case, I have create a specific SO for BundleID/iTunesConnect: [iOS app Bundle ID errors and iTunesConnect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18019287/ios-app-bundle-id-errors-and-itunesconnect)

**Newest update #1**

I decided to drop using wildcard app IDs since I can see that has caused other people problems. Hence I chose the other option in iTunesConnect resulting it in showing me BundleID as being **com.example.appname**. I then made sure 1) my provisioning for distribution used **DistCertificateID.com.example.*** 2) to set CFBunldeIdentifier (in Delphi) as same shown in iTunesConnect. I then built and deployed followed by submitting it to Application Loader. That resulted in error message:

> The Bundle ID **com.example.appname** defined in your Xcode Project
>   does not match the Bundle ID that you entered for this app in iTunes
>   Connect **com.example.appname**.

As you can see, the bundle ID is now the same, but still it complains. I do not understand why :(

**Newest update #2**

I actually made a small typo error last night when I tried above. Guess I was too tired. Above solution works! (I will make it an answer.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ditching the wildcard app ID worked for me. Hence I chose the other option in iTunesConnect resulting it in showing me BundleID as being com.example.appname. I then made sure 1) my provisioning for distribution used DistCertificateID.com.example.* 2) to set CFBunldeIdentifier (in Delphi) as same shown in iTunesConnect. I then built and deployed followed by submitting it to Application Loader.

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with the same problem, I found this link http://embarcadero.newsgroups.archived.at/public.delphi.deployment/201308/1308131098.html

I just hadn't set the CFBundleIdentifier in Debug although I was deploying for Release. I hope this will help you to solve your issue.