# Delphi XE4 iOS Application failed codesign verification

Tags: ios, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe4

I have a problem I can not solve with the Application Loader stating:

> "Application failed codesign verification. The signature was invalid,
>   contains disallowed entitlements, or it was not signed with an iPhone
>   Distribution Certtificate"

Here are some screenshots of my Delphi configuration:

[image]
[image]

Can any one point in the correct direction of things to check?

- I have doublechecked my mobile provisioning is correct.
- I have doublechecked certificate ID correct. (I even tried enter a madeup one just to make sure Delphi would then complain during deploy which it did... Hence that also means codesigning **is** called during deploy)
- The program developer ID is automaticalle fetched by *load* button,
  so I assume that is correct as well.
- I can debug on registered iPhone devices.

I am not sure the two things are related (hence two different SOs), but I am also getting a "Bundle ID" error which is equally mysterious to me: [Delphi XE4 and iOS Application Loader complaining "This bundle is invalid"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18000507/delphi-and-ios-application-loader-complaining-this-bundle-is-invalid)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently solving the Bundle ID error also fixed the certificate error. For reference see: [Delphi XE4 and iOS Application Loader complaining "This bundle is invalid"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18000507/delphi-xe4-and-ios-application-loader-complaining-this-bundle-is-invalid)

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with the same problem, I found this link
http://embarcadero.newsgroups.archived.at/public.delphi.deployment/201308/1308131098.html

I just hadn't set the CFBundleIdentifier in Debug although I was deploying for Release. I hope this will help you to solve your issue.