# How to inspect the Xcode files generated by Delphi?

Tags: ios, delphi, delphi-xe4

Because I have serious problems with Application Loader reporting both codesign + Bundle ID errors, I have become quite desperate to find a solution.

I think I will need to inspect the Xcode files generated by Delphi, so I can better seek help online... Does anyone know if there is a way to see (and possibly change) the files generated by Delphi when building and deploying for release / app store?

For reference, here are the relevant SO entries:

- [Delphi XE4 iOS Application failed codesign verification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18016631/delphi-ios-application-failed-codesign-verification)
- [Delphi XE4 and iOS Application Loader complaining "This bundle is invalid"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18000507/delphi-and-ios-application-loader-complaining-this-bundle-is-invalid)
- [iOS app Bundle ID errors and iTunesConnect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18019287/ios-app-bundle-id-errors-and-itunesconnect)

Comment: Which version of Delphi?

Comment: As there are two separate versions of Delphi that compile apps for iOS (XE2 and XE4), and they use entirely different means of producing that code, you really *must* include the appropriate Delphi version tag if you expect to get an answer.

Comment: XE4 with iOS mobile addon

Comment: @Tom Please add delphi-xe4 tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In lack of other answer, I am going to answer this myself. I learnt elsewhere at Embarcadero forums that the .ipa files generated are actually .zip files which you can unzip and view content of.