# iOS app Bundle ID errors and iTunesConnect

Tags: ios, delphi

As described in this [SO entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18000507/delphi-and-ios-application-loader-complaining-this-bundle-is-invalid), I am getting errors in iOS app Application Uploader.

These are the values I have:

in KeyChain I have this certificate:

```
iPhone Distribution: ExampleCompany (DistCertificateID)
```

In my developer.apple.com account I have defined app:

```
Name: LongReadableName 
Prefix: DistCertificateID 
ID: com.example.*

Name: Xcode iOS Wildcard App ID
Prefix: DistCertificateID 
ID: *
```

These are the errors I am getting:

> This bundle is invalid. The application-identifier entitlement is not
>   formatted correctly; it should contain your 10-character App ID Seed,
>   followed by a dot, followed by your bundle identifier:
>   **0000000000.appname**

and

> The Bundle ID **DistCertificateID.appname** defined in your Xcode Project
>   does not match the Bundle ID that you entered for this app in iTunes
>   Connect **appname**.

Above has let me to conclude I possible submitted the app incorrectly **(?)** to iTunesConnect since that is the only conclusion that makes any sense to me.

(For reference, and if I understood everything correctly, I believe both the specific and wildcard app ID is appropriate for me since I do not need to use inapp-purchases or anything like that.)

When submiting an app in iTunesConnect I can choose between

- Xcode iOS Wildcard App ID - *****
- LongReadableName - **com.example.***

I am completely lost on how I can ever choose a BundleID / BundleID Suffix that obeys both what is written in iTunesConnect (?) and the errors I am getting in Application Uploader right now. Could anyone point me to values I could use that would not collide with Application Uploader requirements?

...

**Newest update #1**

I decided to drop using wildcard app IDs since I can see that has caused other people problems. Hence I chose the other option in iTunesConnect resulting it in showing me BundleID as being **com.example.appname**. I then made sure 1) my provisioning for distribution used **DistCertificateID.com.example.*** 2) to set CFBunldeIdentifier (in Delphi) as same shown in iTunesConnect. I then built and deployed followed by submitting it to Application Loader. That resulted in error message:

> The Bundle ID **com.example.appname** defined in your Xcode Project
>   does not match the Bundle ID that you entered for this app in iTunes
>   Connect **com.example.appname**.

As you can see, the bundle ID is now the same, but still it complains. I do not understand why :(

**Newest update #2**

I actually made a small typo error last night when I tried above. Guess I was too tired. Above solution works! (I will make it an answer.)

Answer (score 0):

Ditching the wildcard app ID worked for me. Hence I chose the other option in iTunesConnect resulting it in showing me BundleID as being com.example.appname. I then made sure 1) my provisioning for distribution used DistCertificateID.com.example.* 2) to set CFBunldeIdentifier (in Delphi) as same shown in iTunesConnect. I then built and deployed followed by submitting it to Application Loader.